# geoJSON: How to create FeatureCollection with dynamic number of Features?

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a list of of Features (all Points) in a list in Python. The Features are dynamic stemming from database data which is updated on a 30 minutes interval.
Hence I never have a static number of features.

I need to generate a Feature Collection with all Features in my list.
However (as far as I know) the syntax for creating a FeatureCollection wants you to pass it all the features.

ie:

```
FeatureClct = FeatureCollection(feature1, feature2, feature3)
```

How does one generate a FeatureCollection without knowing how many features there will be beforehand? Is there a way to append Features to an existing FeatureCollection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation of python-geojson (which i guess you are using, you didn't mention it) you can also pass a list to `FeatureCollection`, just put all the results into a list and you're good to go:

```
feature1 = Point((45, 45));
feature2 = Point((-45, -45));

features = [feature1, feature2];

collection = FeatureCollection(features);
```

https://github.com/frewsxcv/python-geojson#featurecollection

Comment: I think you're my geoJSON god. Answered my question yesterday, and then again today.